# Convert FloatImage type to jpg

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to run a `mapreduce` job to convert images into base 64 format. I have the images stored in a folder in jpeg format. Image by default is taken as a `FloatImage` in `HIPI(hadoop image processing interface)`.

`public static class MyMap extends Mapper<ImageHeader, FloatImage, IntWritable, FloatImage>`

Is it possible to

> 1. Convert FloatImage to jpeg format.
> 2. Read the value from key-value pair in some other format such as BufferedImage.
> 3. Is there anyway I can do this without using HIPI and just by using Hadoop mapreduce.